# 'It's just the way it is' - functional / notional descriptor

Tags: functions

Given a set of expressions, when responding to questions about rules and regulations.

> 'It's just the way it is.'
>
> 'It's the rules.'
>
> 'It's just not allowed.'

What would be a good functional/notional description of this lexical set.

Shutting down? Avoiding explaining? Refusal to engage in discussion?

[EAQUALS from the British Council, page 6](https://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/sites/teacheng/files/Core%20Inventory%20Posters.pdf) shows the kind of functions I'm talking about. Communicative function, what meaning they convey to an interlocutor.

Take the conversation:

> A: So, I'm going to put this over here
>
> B: No, you can't do that.
>
> A: Wait, what, what do you mean? Why not?
>
> B: It's just the rules.
>
> A: I don't get it. That doesn't make any sense.
>
> B: It's just the way it is. Forget about it.

"It's just the way it is." - in this situation, the guy is saying "don't ask questions", or "it's not worth getting into"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having thought about this more, there could be a number of different functions for the phrases, depending on context and prosodic and paralinguistic features of the context.

In this regard, I do believe that it's impossible to pigeon hole without other information. However, it's worth noting as a case where the language is almost phatic, that other features of the contextual environment would come into play.